# How to use expo github actions?

Tags: react-native, expo, github-actions, cicd

https://github.com/expo/expo-github-action

I want to set up the github actions for expo react native to Automate build and deploy in android and ios. I came across one of the medium article and tried out but didn’t work than I came across this github repo but I don’t understand how to use that after downloading  the Zip file , what are the next steps  , how to configure that to a new github repo ?

Answer (score 3):

You don't "download a zip file" o use *any* action.

You add a [`.github/workflows/` yaml file in which you *declare* which action to use](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/introduction-to-github-actions#create-an-example-workflow), with which parameters.

That is what the [Example section of `expo/expo-github-action`](https://github.com/expo/expo-github-action#example-workflows) shows: that will trigger the action on GitHub side (remote side) whenever (in the example) the `main` branch is updated.

You can find [*a lot* of projects using that particular workflow on GitHub](https://github.com/search?l=&q=%22expo%2Fexpo-github-action%22%20language%3AYAML&type=code). [DeFiChange/payment.fiat2defi.ch](https://github.com/DeFiChange/payment.fiat2defi.ch) is one, with its [`.github/workflows/main.yml`](https://github.com/DeFiChange/payment.fiat2defi.ch/blob/96df18733be8a4d68356e7645df1967c0e4a765f/.github/workflows/main.yml#L10-L34), and its [action logs](https://github.com/DeFiChange/payment.fiat2defi.ch/actions).